# Bootstrap 3 Datetimepicker 3.0.0 - make a week start on Monday

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, asp.net-mvc-5, datetimepicker, eonasdan-datetimepicker

There are few reasons I use Bootstrap 3 [Datetimepicker 3.0.0](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Bootstrap.v3.Datetimepicker/) in my MVC 5 project.

Any idea how to offset week start so it starts from Monday? Language tag also not working.

```
 $(function () {
    $('#PickupTime').datetimepicker({
     weekStart: 1
    });
 });
```

This is not working because it is not the same bootstrap-datapicker.js

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of using moment.js I used moment-with-langs.js (I guess it came with default package ASP.NET MVC 5).

By calling:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#DateTime').datetimepicker({
        language: "hr"
    });
</script>
```

thing works, finally the calender starts from monday.

UPDATE:
Even better, add key to **web.config**

```
<appSettings>    
    <add key="Culture" value="hr" />
</appSettings>
```

and then

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(document).on('focus', '#Date', function () {
        $(this).datetimepicker({
            locale: '@System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Culture"]',
            format: 'DD:MM:YYYY',
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 34):

If you are using moment.js from v2.8.1 onwards, add the below code before calling datetimepicker().

```
moment.updateLocale('en', {
  week: { dow: 1 } // Monday is the first day of the week
});

$('#DateTime').datetimepicker();
```

If you are using old version of moment.js, do the following

```
moment.lang('en', {
  week: { dow: 1 }
});

$('#DateTime').datetimepicker();
```

Comment: This works as expected. Shows Monday as the first day on the calendar. In addition to this i needed the Monday and Sunday from any date they picked.

 i.e if they choose 08/09/2018 (MM/DD/YYYY) then i needed 08/06/2018 and 08/12/2018 . to Get those I used the ```Weekday()``` function. i.e ```moment(new Date()).weekday(6).format("MM/DD/YYYY")``` which gave me Sunday for the week
https://momentjs.com/docs/#/get-set/weekday/

Answer (score 7):

You can also override the dow value via the locale when calling datetimepicker()

```
$('#myid').datetimepicker({
    format:'YYYY-MM-DD',
    locale:  moment.locale('en', {
        week: { dow: 1 }
    }),
});
```

Comment: Worked like a sharm! Thanks

Answer (score 4):

According to the options for Datetimepicker this is not possible. It only supports the following properties:

```
$.fn.datetimepicker.defaults = {
    pickDate: true,                 //en/disables the date picker
    pickTime: true,                 //en/disables the time picker
    useMinutes: true,               //en/disables the minutes picker
    useSeconds: true,               //en/disables the seconds picker
    useCurrent: true,               //when true, picker will set the value to the current date/time     
    minuteStepping:1,               //set the minute stepping
    minDate:`1/1/1900`,               //set a minimum date
    maxDate: ,     //set a maximum date (defaults to today +100 years)
    showToday: true,                 //shows the today indicator
    language:'en',                  //sets language locale
    defaultDate:"",                 //sets a default date, accepts js dates, strings and moment objects
    disabledDates:[],               //an array of dates that cannot be selected
    enabledDates:[],                //an array of dates that can be selected
    icons = {
        time: 'glyphicon glyphicon-time',
        date: 'glyphicon glyphicon-calendar',
        up:   'glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-up',
        down: 'glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down'
    }
    useStrict: false,               //use "strict" when validating dates  
    sideBySide: false,              //show the date and time picker side by side
    daysOfWeekDisabled:[]          //for example use daysOfWeekDisabled: [0,6] to disable weekends 
};
```

[Source: http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/#options](http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/#options)

You can disable the weekend if you don't want to see sunday.

Comment: But still left column is sunday, and people expect monday

Comment: In bootstrap-datapicker.js I have offseted the names, but only names get mooved, not the dates itself, so entire calender is not correct. Eaven treid changing in moment.js, but same thing.

Comment: Any replacement sugestions?

Comment: Finally i switched to https://github.com/smalot/bootstrap-datetimepicker but will follow development of first one.

Comment: NO i didn't. It is buggy and simply not working. Gong back to original.

Answer (score 4):

I have just done! In moment.js change this line:

```
_week : {
    dow : 1, // Sunday is the first day of the week.
    doy : 6  // The week that contains Jan 1st is the first week of the year. 
},
```

'dow' MUST BE 1 and the week starts at Monday.

Answer (score 0):

open *jquery.datetimepicker.js* and find variable "**dayOfWeekStart**" and set it to **1**

Comment: The OP was referring to [Eonasdan Bootstrap-Datepicker](http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/). This has nothing to do with jQuery's datepicker.

Comment: Nothing to do with OP's question.

Comment: not edit, but use as option $(".dataPicker").datetimepicker({ dayOfWeekStart: 1 });

Answer (score 0):

```
'locale' => [
    'firstDay' => 1
]
```

Answer (score 0):

I stumbled upon the same question, and i'm using:

- Bootstrap3 Datetimepicker ([4.14.30](http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/Changelog/#41430))
- Moment ([2.10.3](https://github.com/moment/moment/releases/tag/2.10.3))

And, following the answer of [user3928861](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3928861/user3928861) I found the answer on line 961 of moment.js as follows:

```
var defaultLocaleWeek = {
    dow : 1, // Sunday is the first day of the week.
    doy : 6  // The week that contains Jan 1st is the first week of the year.
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Datetimepicker has an option to set that to match wherever you are in the world (see the locale option http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/Options/#locale)

You can manually override it

```
$('#DateTime').datetimepicker({
    locale: moment.local('en')
});
```