# Bootstrap Datetimepicker starts with monday

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-datetimepicker, eonasdan-datetimepicker

I want to my calendar week start with monday. Im using [**Bootstrap Datetimepicker**](https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/), but I don't know how to do that. There's my [**JSFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/eatmailyo/ekm0on2a/15/).

This is my jQuery for datetimepicker

```
$(function () {
    $('.datetimepickerinline').datetimepicker({
      inline: true
  });
  $('.datetimepickerinline').on('change dp.change', function(e){
    $('input').val($(this).data('date'));
  });
});
```

I cant find any solutions in documentation, that's why Im asking it there :)

Comment: Switch to [bootstrap-datetimepicker](https://github.com/smalot/bootstrap-datetimepicker)! It's having plenty of options to customize

Comment: your HTML markup is wrong, you don't need JS for setting it. It's literally in the documentation.  Your title of the question also differs to the actual question.

Comment: @tejashsoni111 that solution doesnt work for me. if you can add to my code, then thats gonna be nice :)

Comment: @DanielsJirgensons, check out this fiddle [https://jsfiddle.net/ekm0on2a/16/](https://jsfiddle.net/ekm0on2a/16/). I used the same solution provided at [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24410685/bootstrap-3-datetimepicker-3-0-0-week-starts-at-monday](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24410685/bootstrap-3-datetimepicker-3-0-0-week-starts-at-monday)

Comment: @tejashsoni111 oh, nice. write this at answer, that I can mark as answered :)

Comment: @DanielsJirgensons note that the datetimepicker allows localization, if you add the [`locale`](https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/Options/#locale) option you will have the calendar according the given locale. If you just need to change the start of the week, change moment `dow` setting for english locale as suggested in the linked answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to make changes for the `moment` js option as implemented in answer here : [Bootstrap 3 Datetimepicker 3.0.0 - week starts at Monday](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24410685/bootstrap-3-datetimepicker-3-0-0-week-starts-at-monday)

JSFIDDLE : https://jsfiddle.net/ekm0on2a/16/

```
$(function () {
    moment.locale('en', {
        week: { dow: 1 } // Monday is the first day of the week
    });
    $('.datetimepickerinline').datetimepicker({
          inline: true
      });
      $('.datetimepickerinline').on('change dp.change', function(e){
        $('input').val($(this).data('date'));
      });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You could set the `locale` to the correct value, so everyone should have it correct in their country.

```
$('.datetimepickerinline').datetimepicker({
   inline: true,
   locale: 'de'
});
```

Setting that to germany, the week starts with monday and also the text is in german.